# ManagedProperty with CDI Managed Beans is null in other Managed Beans

Tags: java, cdi, jsf-2.2

so I have three **CDI Managed Beans** and In two of these I'm injecting the `loginMB` so I can use the `Session` properties in it, but  they are both throwing `NullPointerException` :

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

@Named(value = "loginMB")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginMB implements Serializable{

private NomadUser usuarioEnSession;
private UserSettings configuracionUsuarioEnSession;

public void login(){}
   // login method .... 
   // where I already verified that both usuarioEnSession & config... != null
}
```

- **Both have the settter of the ManagedProperty**

MB 1:

```
@Named(value = "fotoPerfilMB")
@RequestScoped
public class FotoPerfilMB implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{loginMB}")
    private LoginMB loginMB;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        // this  throws NullPOinterException
        loginMB.getConfiguracionUsuarioEnSession();
    }

}
```

MB 2:

```
@Named(value = "imagenesMB")
@RequestScoped
public class ImagenesMB implements Serializable {

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{loginMB}")
    private LoginMB loginMB;
    @EJB
    private UserImagesFacade servicioImagenes;
    private int idUsuarioEnSession;
    private NomadUser usuarioEnSession;
    private List<UserImages> listaImagenes;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            usuarioEnSession = loginMB.getUsuarioEnSession();
            idUsuarioEnSession = usuarioEnSession.getId();
            listaImagenes = servicioImagenes.listaImagenes(idUsuarioEnSession);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // this is allways thrown
            System.err.println("loginMB  is null");
        }
    }
```

As you can see I've been playing around with `try-catch` statements, printing the `ManagedProperty` value  but I just can't seem to understand why its **null**, here's the stack trace. Thanks in advance.

This happens when I remove the `try-catch` statements, and I understand its because there's an `Exception` being thrown in the `@postConstruct` method and I now its  `NullPointerException` from the `loginMB  ManagedProperty`

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049:
Unable to invoke public void co.nomad.managedBeans.FotoPerfilMB.init()
on co.nomad.managedBeans.FotoPerfilMB@672d4b74
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty much normal, you're mixing CDI annotations with JSF annotations.

This is a bad thing because JSF keeps its own managed bean container and CDI does pretty much the same. This kind of setup will lead at best to strange behaviours.

I would advise to stick to CDI annotations or use only JSF annotations in managed beans and use Spring for the others beans such as services or else.

Comment: I tried also  `@Inject` instead of  `@managedProperty` but I get the same result.  ¿Are you referring to something besides this ? could you please be more specific .